# Creating an ID to go along with my data when querying SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a little problem when querying data. I have a table that looks like this:

```
Value1       Value2
--------------------
ABC          123 
BCD          123
DCE          123
EFG          123
```

What I'm hoping to do is, basically only select `VALUE1` from this table, however, I'd like to assign an ID to go along with each value...

Desired end result

```
ID      Value1
--------------
1       ABC
2       BCD
3       DCE
4       EFG
```

Is something like that possible? I'd hope to have the end result to be in alphabetical order and ID's assigned based in ASCENDING order. Also, would hope that this query can be in place even if more VALUE1 values are added in the table (dynamic)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window function `row_number` while selecting:

```
select row_number() over (
        order by value1
        ) as id,
    value1
from your_table;
```